# How to retrieve the catalog of available azure vm sizes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm having issues for a C# azure function where the goal is to create a routine that gathers all the vm sizes available on azure, regardless the subscription, since we want all the vm size types that azure has in store.

Unfortunatly, the available azure API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list) that I found requires a subscription id, which is not my goal.

I would like to know if there is an alternative that could solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to access the data without a subscription?

Comment: An Azure Subscription is free (you only need to pay when you use resources). And VM size availability needs to factor in the regions you are interested in – not all VM classes are available everywhere.